# Finding statistical outliers in timestamp intervals with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We have a bunch of devices in the field (various customer sites) that "call home" at regular intervals, configurable at the device but defaulting to 4 hours.

I have a view in SQL Server that displays the following information in descending chronological order:

```
DeviceInstanceId uniqueidentifier not null
AccountId int not null
CheckinTimestamp datetimeoffset(7) not null
SoftwareVersion string not null
```

Each time the device checks in, it will report its id and current software version which we store in a SQL Server db.

Some of these devices are in places with flaky network connectivity, which obviously prevents them from operating properly.  There are also a bunch in datacenters where administrators regularly forget about it and change firewall/ proxy settings, accidentally preventing outbound communication for the device.  We need to proactively identify this bad connectivity so we can start investigating the issue before finding out from an unhappy customer... because even if the problem is 99% certainly on their end, they tend to feel (and as far as we are concerned, correctly) that we should know about it and be bringing it to their attention rather than vice-versa.

I am trying to come up with a way to query all distinct `DeviceInstanceId` that have currently not checked in for a period of 150% their normal check-in interval.  For example, let's say device `87C92D22-6C31-4091-8985-AA6877AD9B40` has, for the last 1000 checkins, checked in every 4 hours or so (give or take a few seconds)... but the last time it checked in was just a little over 6 hours ago now.  This is information I would like to highlight for immediate review, along with device `E117C276-9DF8-431F-A1D2-7EB7812A8350` which normally checks in every 2 hours, but it's been a little over 3 hours since the last check-in.

It seems relatively straightforward to brute-force this, looping through all the devices, examining the average interval between check-ins, seeing what the last check-in was, comparing that to current time, etc... but there's thousands of these, and the device count grows larger every day.  I need an efficient query to quickly generate this list of uncommunicative devices at least every hour... I just can't picture how to write that query.

Can someone help me with this?  Maybe point me in the right direction?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to come up with a way to query all distinct DeviceInstanceId that have currently not checked in for a period of 150% their normal check-in interval.

I think you can do:

```
select *
from (select DeviceInstanceId,
             datediff(second, min(CheckinTimestamp), max(CheckinTimestamp)) / nullif(count(*) - 1, 0) as avg_secs,
             max(CheckinTimestamp) as max_CheckinTimestamp
      from t
      group by DeviceInstanceId
     ) t
where max_CheckinTimestamp < dateadd(second, - avg_secs * 1.5, getdate());
```

Comment: Hmm this seems close but the outliers look really weird.  I don't think I can use `avg` for this, as some of these had outages in the past and that makes the average seconds quite strange.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs . . . This answers the question that you have asked *here*.  If you have a different question, ask it as a new question.

Comment: I don't think that's the case? I did say that there are outages with a fair amount of frequency... it seems the answer should be determining some kind of median rather than an average to compensate for this (I would think)